# How to show json output in table

Tags: php, html, json

I have written following code to call a json and show output.

`

```
$data = array("user" => "$username", "pass" => "$password", "msisdn" => "$msisdn", "receiver_msisdn" => "", "trx_type" => "", "from_date" => "$startdate", "to_date" => "$enddate");
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('http://ip:port/call_center/account/statementsearch');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;


    ?>
```

Now how can I show the output of the json call in a table?

Comment: What `var_dump($result)` shows?

Comment: This is how my output looks like
`{"response_code":"0000","transactions":[{"trx_id":"1234","trx_status":"COMPLETED","trx_type":"test","from_account":"121212","to_account":"121212","trx_amount":"-500","trx_fee":"0","trx_commission":"0","trx_timestamp":"2016-02-08 21:56:38.730","current_balance":"2111212.4"}`

Comment: I just want to show the portion inside [... ] in the table.

Comment: I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to decode the json string and in that function set the `assoc` parameter to `TRUE` to convert the objects into associative arrays. And then loop through the array to display it in a table, like this:

```
// your code

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

$arr = json_decode($result, true);

echo "<table>";
foreach($arr['transactions'] as $a){
    foreach($a as $key => $value){
        echo "<tr><td>" . $key . "</td><td>" . $value . "</td></tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rajdeep. But this soultion is providing only the first value of the array. I will have to print all the values i get from the call. so [0] has to be incremented to the length of the array. Can you help me regarding this?

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot @Rajdeep.

Answer (score 0):

Please try "json_encode" for return data in json.

```
$data = array("user" => "$username", "pass" => "$password", "msisdn" => "$msisdn", "receiver_msisdn" => "", "trx_type" => "", "from_date" => "$startdate", "to_date" => "$enddate");
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('http://ip:port/call_center/account/statementsearch');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: I can already show the output of the call. Please see my comment above. I want to show the output in a table.